# MySQL Workbench Erro "Unknown File Encoding"

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, mysql

Estou com um problema, eu fiz backup do meu banco, porém ao carregar o `script` no `MySQL Workbench`, recebo uma mensagem dizendo: `"Unknown File Encoding"`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu escolho `utf8` recebo esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só consigo abrir se escolher `latin1`, mas aí os caracteres acentuados ficam errados, como por exemplo: `SÃ©rgio Gomes`

Não sei se é devido a algum erro meu na criação do banco, problemas com as ferramentas, então se alguém puder ajudar a configurar corretamente a exibição dos caracteres acentuados, fico grato. Obrigado.

Comment: Essa resposta no SOen sugere que isso pode ser um bug do MySQL Workbench: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12348391/540552 - Já experimentou o [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)?

Comment: Não conheço, mas  vou verificar e posto o resultado, Obrigado.

Comment: @Rodrigo, como é que vc está carregando esse arquivo no workbench?

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema relatado acima e descobri o que aconteceu NO MEU CASO.

Meus backups estavam sendo codificados corretamente no utf-8. Até que um dia ele começou a dar esse erro relatado acima.

Descobri que foi porque eu tinha acabado de criar uma tabela que registrava num campo um DOCUMENTO, que podia ser pdf, jpg, png... enfim.

O problema era esse. Não estava registrando apenas o nome do arquivo e sim, o arquivo em si. Isso estava causando o erro.

Apaguei o registro da tabela e o backup funcionou perfeitamente.

Em vez de guardar no banco o arquivo, coloquei pro banco guardar apenas o nome do arquivo e o caminho. O arquivo passou a ser guardado no próprio servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende de qual o encoding usado para gerar o seu backup, se você não definiu o encoding correto para gerar o seu backup você vai ter problemas de acentuação. Veja que na mensagem de erro do mysql informa que seu arquivo não é UTF-8 (provavelmente deve ter sido gerado como latin), sugiro a você que verifique qual o encoding que esta sendo utilizado pelo seu banco de dados, para isso execute o seguinte comando no seu banco de dados:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "character\_set\_database";
```

e gere novamente o seu backup especificando o encoding (este é um exemplo de um backup usando utf-8 como encoding):

```
mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p dbname -r dump.sql
```